# Magento 2.4.1: Does reCaptch v2 work with Magento 2.4.1?

Tags: magento2.4.1

I added reCaptcha v2 Invisible to the new account creation page, but it doesn't show the reCaptcha icon at the right bottom corner. I wonder if I need to set up reCaptcha v3 Invisible for it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have upgraded to Magento 2.4.1 your previous reCaptcha settings might have been removed.

Magento support reCaptch v2 and v3 and there are new reCaptcha admin settings for Admin and the Storefront under `Stores -> Security`.

Check that you have configured your Google API keys here correctly. reCaptcha does not always show when testing, check your source code, or console debug to see if you can find the reCaptcha code on your page.

[image]